# Convert AES/ECB/NoPadding in java to Nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, nestjs, cryptojs

I want the below java code to be converted into nodejs

```
JAVA

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] buf = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        baos.write(buf);
        int len = 16 - (baos.size() % 16);
        baos.write(new byte[len]);
        buf = baos.toByteArray();
    }
    buf = cipher.doFinal(buf);
    final String data2 = Base64.encodeBase64String(buf);
```

I have done it using crypto but due to the padding issue i am not able to execute cipher.final. Any ideas to resolve this issue?

```
NodeJS
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    var keybase64 = Buffer.from(app_secret, 'utf8');
    var data1 = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8');
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ecb', app_secret, '');
    cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    let result = cipher.update(data1,'utf8','base64');
    result += cipher.final('base64')
    console.log('result', result)
```

Comment: Try [`cipher.setAutoPadding`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_autopadding)

Comment: I have added it, due to which i cannot execute cipher.final().

Comment: Which points at maybe you got the bits wrong. Is it 256 bit cipher?

Comment: The API which i am calling needs the data in block of 16 bytes, it is there i am going wrong. not sure how can i convert the result data to block of 16 bytes

Comment: 16 bytes would mean 128 bit encryption. So you should use AES 128 instead of AES 256.

Comment: i changed it to 128 bit AES and this is the response i get from the app i am calling"Decrypt failed:Input length not multiple of 16 bytes".

So basically the app is expecting the data be a multiple block of length 16 bytes each.

Comment: Your cipher.init is ...NoPadding and that impliciets an input of exact (multiple of) 16 bytes - this is regarding to the AES blocklength. If you should have a plaintext shorter you need to pad  (fill it up) to 16s.Or use a cipher.init. ..PKCS5 / 7 padding on both sides.

Comment: Michael, if you see the java code they are using No padding.. i need to use the same the same thing, as there application will decrypt the data, considering it is no padding. I cannot have the PKCS5 or PKCS7 padding.. i am not sure how to generate the block size of 16 with no padding